# I can't generalize the path in the ShellExecuteA command

Tags: c++, winapi

If I put the name of the user, it works. But it just doesn't do anything if I run it like below. It should work on Windows 10/11;
I am also a beginner and would appreciate any information I can get about using `ShellExecuteA`.

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "rundll32.exe", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Downloads\\[image name].png", NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

This is supposed to open said image in Windows Image Viewer. And it does if I put my actual username instead of `%USERNAME%`.

As for my purpose, I want to make a C++ program that downloads a photo (got that working) and then opens it;

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath

Comment: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Calin\Documents\CPP\test.cpp).
cannot open source file "shlobj_core.h"
any ideea why this happends on vscode?

Comment: Did you include windows.h in angle brackets?

Comment: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Comment: The solution to the question you didn't ask is this: [Launch the default app for a URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app).

Comment: Sorry for not responding but these are all the headers i included
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <processenv.h>
and i get the same error for the last 2

Comment: The `%environment variables%` in the *lpParameters* sting of *ShellExecute* will not be substituted automatically. You need to compose it as @RemyLebeau does.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use environment variables in file paths used with the Shell API (or most other file APIs), like you are attempting to do. You will have to use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa) first, eg:

```
const char* cmdEnv = "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Downloads\\[image name].png";

DWORD len = ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(cmdEnv, nullptr, 0);
std::string cmd(len, '\0');
ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(cmdEnv, cmd.data(), len);

ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "rundll32.exe", cmd.c_str(), nullptr, SW_HIDE);
```

That being said, you really should not be hard-coding any file paths that involve system-defined folders, like the user profile, since the actual location of such folders can differ across systems. Instead, you should use [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) to get the actual path of the desired folder (in this case, `FOLDERID_Downloads`), and then append to it as needed.

For example:

```
std::wstring GetKnownFolderPath(KNOWNFOLDERID folderID)
{
    PWSTR pPath = nullptr;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(folderID, 0, nullptr, &pPath);
    std::wstring str = pPath;
    CoTaskMemFree(pPath);
    return str;
}

std::wstring cmd = L"\"" + GetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles) + L"\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen " + GetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads) + L"\\[image name].png";
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"rundll32.exe", cmd.c_str(), nullptr, SW_HIDE);
```